# Wiremock stubs for an API client that has hardcoded urls

Tags: java, spring-boot, wiremock, braintree-sandbox

I am trying to test a small service with wiremock tests.

I am fine with stubbing out most of the third party service URLs however I run into problems when using client libraries that have their sanbox URL hardcoded.

The current example is for Braintree.
I want to stub a return for a call to "https://api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com:443"
I cannot override that value in the test properties.

(Ref for the hardcoding https://github.com/braintree/braintree_java/blob/9f619bb0dd019921caed1f344046078469fbf1f8/src/main/java/com/braintreegateway/Environment.java)

Is there a way I can configure wiremock to be aware of calls to https://api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com: and return a stubbed response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the HTTP client in the Braintree lib respects Java's proxy setting system properties, you can configure WireMock to be a forward proxy (or browser proxy as WireMock's docs call it), allow it to intercept calls to any external domain.

This doc explains how to do this using the new proxy configurer utility class: http://wiremock.org/docs/multi-domain-mocking/.

Essentially you'd want to do something like this:

```java
JvmProxyConfigurer.configureFor(wireMockServer);

 wireMockServer.stubFor(get("/stuff")
    .withHost(equalTo("api.sandbox.braintreegateway.com"))
    .willReturn(okJson("{ ... }")));

// Test something that uses the Braintree client lib
```

Comment: Thanks for the pointer tom. To set this up for https would I set the wiremock server up with .httpsPort(443) ?

Comment: Yes, if you want to use it as an endpoint. However, I wouldn't advise it if you're using WireMock exclusively as a proxy as most clients don't work properly proxying via HTTPS. You can proxy to both HTTP and HTTPS endpoints via an HTTP proxy and this will remain secure.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Braintree SDK, but from what I see you use it by providing the `Environment` to the `BraintreeGateway` object: https://github.com/braintree/braintree_java/tree/master#quick-start-example

I would create a dedicated test `Environment` instance containing Wiremock URLs and provide it to the `BraintreeGateway` in my integration tests.